# unwind segue works with button but not programmatically - why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue, master-detail

Well I'm not having a good start with Objective C and Xcode - this it the second time I've had to come here for help in one simple project - embarrassing!

My master (Squad) view controller loads a detail (Pilot) view controller, which in turn loads a third view controller (SelectNewPilot) with a modal segue.  This works fine.  If you press the cancel button on the SelectNewPilot (modal) view it unwinds to the Pilot (detail) view controller.  In the Pilot view controller I have this code:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    UIViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    if([source isKindOfClass:[Mz0SelectNewPilotViewController class]])
    {
        if ([(Mz0SelectNewPilotViewController *)source pilot] == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"We cancelled selecting a new pilot");
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Unwind" sender:self];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"We selected %@", [[(Mz0SelectNewPilotViewController *)source pilot] name]);
        }
    }
}
```

so that if nothing was selected in the SelectNewPilot (modal) controller (i.e. it was cancelled) then the Pilot controller automatically unwinds further back to the Squad (master) controller.  This produces the following error:

```
2014-03-13 00:45:07.578 Squad Builder[3149:70b] *** Assertion failure in -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.120.3/UINavigationController.m:4886
2014-03-13 00:45:07.581 Squad Builder[3149:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01b629e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018e28e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01b62848 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x014c20de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   UIKit                               0x006edbe0 -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:] + 302
    5   UIKit                               0x006edaad -[UINavigationController popToViewController:animated:] + 56
    6   UIKit                               0x006e633f __90-[UINavigationController segueForUnwindingToViewController:fromViewController:identifier:]_block_invoke + 142
    7   UIKit                               0x00b197ac -[UIStoryboardSegue perform] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x00c7d623 -[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate _perform:] + 554
    9   UIKit                               0x00b090b7 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018f4880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    11  UIKit                               0x005a67f9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    12  UIKit                               0x008938bf -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 139
    13  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018f4880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    14  UIKit                               0x005a67f9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    15  UIKit                               0x005a6785 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    16  UIKit                               0x006a7fe1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    17  UIKit                               0x006a83d6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    18  UIKit                               0x006a7653 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    19  UIKit                               0x005e621d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    20  UIKit                               0x005e6e11 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
    21  UIKit                               0x005b8a32 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    22  UIKit                               0x005a2793 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01aebf7f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x01aeb90b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x01b089ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x01b081d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x01b07feb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x03a175ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x03a1742b GSEventRun + 104
    30  UIKit                               0x005a53db UIApplicationMain + 1225
    31  Squad Builder                       0x0000a6bd main + 141
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x021ad701 start + 1
)
```

If I comment out the line
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Unwind" sender:self];
then it works fine, you just have to press cancel on the Pilot controller to get back to the Squad controller.  My question is why does that unwind segue (from Pilot to Squad) work when you use the button to trigger it, but not when called programmatically (it's the same unwind segue, I just applied an identifier to the one the cancel button uses)?

The unwindToList method in the squad controller completes, so I'm not sure what is being called that causes the error.  What is making the segue try to pop something?  Is that set in the storyboard somewhere?

The unwindToList method from the Squad controller is below (both NSLog outputs appear before the error):

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    NSLog(@"Unwound to Squad");
    Mz0PilotViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    Mz0Card *pilot = [source pilot];
    if ([pilot isKindOfClass:[Mz0Card class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Adding new pilot: %@", [pilot name]);
        if(![_testData containsObject:pilot])
        {
            [_testData addObject:pilot];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Finished unwinding to Squad");
}
```

Update: I've just noticed another error before it starts printing the output (and then the final error):

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <Mz0SquadViewController: 0x8dc8720>
```

Is this because it's trying to unwind too quickly? Is there a way I can tell it not to unwind from Pilot to Squad until the first unwind (from SelectNewPilot to Pilot) is complete?

Comment: Double check your segue names on storyboard.  `NSLog(@"%@",segue);` might be enlightening.

Comment: The segue must be working - both the NSLog commands in unwindToList in Squad complete, so the segue is getting there, it's just also trying to pop something, which it doesn't do when triggered by a button in the storyboard.
edit: just confirmed with NSLog - it is the right one

Comment: I've just noticed another error before it starts printing the output:
    Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <Mz0SquadViewController: 0x8dc8720>
Is this because it's trying to unwind too quickly?  Is there a way I can tell it not to unwind from Pilot to Squad until the first unwind (from SelectNewPilot to Pilot) is complete?